# Querying ManyToMany in Django giving me duplicate results

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.9

I have two models

```
class Tag(models.Model):
   key = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Post(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I m trying to filter out posts with a list of tags. Lets say tags `heat` and `warm`. I will get a list of tags in my api function(`['heat', 'warm']`). I want to filter all Post data which have tags whose keys are in the list. I tried many types and didn't get correct output. Is there a way to do this on single query?

Comment: Can you show what output do you except ? I'm not sure to understand what you need.

Answer (score 7):

All Post with this tag key equal to `heat` or `warm`

```
Post.objects.filter(tags__key_in=['heat', 'warm'])
```

Add distinct to avoid duplicate :

```
Post.objects.filter(tags__key_in=['heat', 'warm']).distinct()
```

Answer (score 7):

While [Wilfried's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957118) is correct and perfectly fine for a lot of use cases, it's worth noting that on the SQL level, `DISTINCT` may have a performance impact, especially if you expect you query to match a significant portion of your data (depending on DB and table sizes; see e.g. [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177162/how-to-make-distinct-on-faster-in-postgresql) and [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct) for more details).

Another slightly more verbose option, which avoids this pitfall, is using a `through` model and a `Subquery` (introduced in django 1.11). Based on OPs code:

```python
class Tag(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='Tagging')

class Tagging(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and the respective query:

```python
tags = Tagging.objects.filter(tag__key__in=['heat', 'warm'])
Post.objects.filter(pk__in=models.Subquery(tags.values('post__pk')))
```

Using `.explain(analyze=True)` (introduced in django 2.1) will help you make an informed decision.

Comment: This is much better. A distinct query can be disastrous to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding [Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63378267/6229845), you don't actually need to create a new "through" model. Django already does it for you (it creates a table that connects 2 models by primary keys). You can retrieve the "through" model like so:

```py
PostTag = Post.tags.through
```

Then in order to filter by certain tags efficiently and without the use of `distinct` you can use an `Exists` subquery combined with an `OuterRef` expression. See [Filtering on a Subquery() or Exists() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#filtering-on-a-subquery-or-exists-expressions) for more details. In this case it should be something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

desired_tags = ['heat', 'warm']
PostTag = Post.tags.through
post_tags = PostTag.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk'), tag__key__in=desired_tags)
posts_with_tags = Post.objects.filter(Exists(post_tags))
```